# Reverse iterator returns garbage when optimized

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, reverse, compiler-optimization

I have a `AsIterator` template class which takes a numeric-like type, in this example just an `int`, and converts it into an iterator (`++` and `--` increment and decrement the number, and `operator*` just returns a reference to it).

This works fine **unless it's wrapped into a `std::reverse_iterator` and compiled with any optimization** (`-O` is enough). When I optimize the binary, the compiler strips out the dereference call to the `reverse_iterator` and replaces it with some weird value. It must be noted that it still **makes the correct number of iterations**. It's just the value obtained by reverse iterator that is garbage.

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
class AsIterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T> {
    T v;
public:
    AsIterator(const T & init) : v(init) {}

    T &operator*() { return v; }

    AsIterator &operator++() { ++v; return *this; }
    AsIterator operator++(int) { AsIterator copy(*this); ++(*this); return copy; }
    AsIterator &operator--() { --v; return *this; }
    AsIterator operator--(int) { AsIterator copy(*this); --(*this); return copy; }

    bool operator!=(const AsIterator &other) const {return v != other.v;}
    bool operator==(const AsIterator &other) const {return v == other.v;}
};

typedef std::reverse_iterator<AsIterator<int>> ReverseIt;

int main() {
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    printf("Insert two integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    if (b < a) std::swap(a, b);

    AsIterator<int> real_begin(a);
    AsIterator<int> real_end(b);
    for (ReverseIt rev_it(real_end); rev_it != ReverseIt(real_begin); ++rev_it) {
        printf("%d\n", *rev_it);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This should supposingly loop down from the highest inserted number to the lowest and print them, such as in this run (compiled with `-O0`):

```
Insert two integers: 1 4 
3
2
1
```

What I get with `-O` is instead:

```
Insert two integers: 1 4 
1
0
0
```

You can [try it online here](http://cpp.sh/3htz); the numbers may vary but they're always "wrong" when optimizing the binary.

---

What I've tried:

- hardcoding the input integers is enough to produce the same result;
- the issue persists with *gcc 5.4.0* and *clang 3.8.0*, also when using *libc++*;
- making all the objects `const` (i.e. returning `const int &`, and declaring all variables as such) doesn't fix it;
- using the `reverse_iterator` in the same way on for example some `std::vector<int>` works fine;
- if I just use `AsIterator<int>` for a normal forward or backward loop it works fine.
- in my tests, the constant `0` that is printed is actually *hardcoded* by the compiler, the calls to `printf` all look like this when compiled with `-S -O`:

```
    movl    $.L.str.2, %edi  # .L.str.2 is "%d\n"
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   printf
```

Given the consistency of *clang* and *gcc*'s behavior here I am pretty sure they're doing it right and I misunderstood, but I really can't see it.

Comment: Interestingly, `-fsanitize=undefined` "fixes" it. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddcc7bbf26ab9da2

Comment: One more data point: g++ 4.4 does print out `3 2 1` even with `-O2` while 4.7 prints `0 0 0` for me. This screams of undefined behavior but I can't see it yet.

Comment: @BaummitAugen In the original context where this MVCE is taken from, also adding a print statement inside `operator*` would fix it, but not in this example.

Comment: @MarkB also compiling with c++03 gives a series of 1s instead of 0s, but `fsanitize=undefined` doesn't report anything.

Comment: I cannot spot the UB either. This is frustrating and interesting...

Comment: Check to see if your `operator*` is getting called during decrement when optimized, also try accessing `.current` to get the value of the base iterator every time.`

Comment: Returning `T` instead of `T&` prints the correct values: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6etDOfYbvtzqknay

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looking at `std::reverse_iterator`'s *libstdc++* implementation reveals something interesting:

```
  /**
   *  @return  A reference to the value at @c --current
   *
   *  This requires that @c --current is dereferenceable.
   *
   *  @warning This implementation requires that for an iterator of the
   *           underlying iterator type, @c x, a reference obtained by
   *           @c *x remains valid after @c x has been modified or
   *           destroyed. This is a bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/PR51823
  */
  _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR reference
  operator*() const
  {
    _Iterator __tmp = current;
     return *--__tmp;
  }
```

The `@warning` section tells us that a requirement of the underlying iterator type is that `*x` must remain valid even after the underlying iterator is modified/destroyed.

Looking at the [mentioned bug link](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR51823) reveals more interesting information:

> > at some point between C++03 and C++11 the definition of reverse_iterator::operator* was changed to clarify this, making libstdc++'s implementation wrong.  The standard now says:
> >
> > [ Note: This operation must use an auxiliary member variable rather than a temporary variable to avoid returning a reference that persists beyond the lifetime of its associated iterator. (See 24.2.) —end note ]
>
> comment by Jonathan Wakely (2012)

So it looks like a bug... but at the end of the topic:

> > The definition of reverse_iterator has been reverted to the C++03 version, which does not use an extra member, so "stashing iterators" can not be used with reverse_iterator.
>
> comment by Jonathan Wakely (2014)

So it seems that using `std::reverse_iterator` with "stashing iterators" does indeed lead to UB.

---

Looking at the [DR 2204: **"`reverse_iterator` should not require a second copy of the base iterator"**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3473.html#2204) further clarifies the issue:

> This note in 24.5.1.3.4 [reverse.iter.op.star]/2:
>
> > **[ Note: This operation must use an auxiliary member variable rather than a temporary variable to avoid returning a reference that persists beyond the lifetime of its associated iterator. (See 24.2.) —end note ]**
> >
> > *[my note: I think that the above note would fix your UB issue]*
>
> is incorrect because such iterator implementations are ruled out by 24.2.5 [forward.iterators]/6, where it says:
>
> > **If a and b are both dereferenceable, then a == b if and only if *a and *b are bound to the same object.**

Comment: Right, also relevant from the [bug link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51823): *"What you've written is not an iterator, it's a generator."* -- `reverse_iterator` would not work correctly with any non-persistent reference returned by the inner iterator.